# copy content of folder to multiple folders bash

Tags: bash

I want to copy the content of source folder to destination folders in one line, is that possible ?

I have this

```
cp -r source/* dest1 dest2 dest3
```

but it doesn't work, what it does it copies the 3 folders (source dest1 dest2) in dest3 and I want the content from source folder to each dest folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want to make three copies?

```
for dest in dest1 dest2 dest3 ; do
    cp -r source/* "$dest"
done
```

Or, use `xargs` to avoid the loop:

```
echo dest1 dest2 dest3 | xargs -n1 cp -r source/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for`:

```
for dest in dest1 dest2 dest3; do cp -r source/* "$dest"; done
```